# Implement a function with the argument of both types const T & and T&&

Tags: c++, c++17

I am doing humble attempts to implement some specific BST with the interface compatible with std::set and the more attempts I do the more questions I have.

For example, one of the questions is how to minimize code duplication while implementing two overloaded versions of `insert` method:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type & value)
```

and

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(value_type&& value);
```

Currently I implemented the first overload that internally calls a private method FindNodeByKey:

```
template<class T, class Compare = std::less<>, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class my_set
{
   ...

private:

    template <class Key>
    Node * FindNodeByKey(const Key & key) const
    {
        Node * x = m_root;

        //walk down the tree
        while (x != nullptr)
        {
            if (m_comp(key, x->value))
            {
                x = x->left;
            }
            else if (m_comp(x->value, key))
            {
                x = x->right;
            }
            else
            {
                return x;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    Comparer m_comp;
}
```

where m_comp is a `Comparer` instance, `Node` is a structure containing BST links and the value of type T, `Key` is any type the `Comparer` supports and in particular `value_type`.

1) What is the optimal way to implement `FindNodeByKey` with the parameter of type `Key &&` (for using with the second `insert` overload)? Is there a way to avoid its code duplication?

2) And should I pass `Key &&` to the comparer?

3) Also honestly I do not quite understand why I use `std::less<>`, but std::set uses `std::less<T>` as the default comparer.

**EDIT1:**

`value_type` is not guaranteed to have copy constructor (be copyable).

Comment: BTW: If it's `const`, it should return a `const Node*`. I realize it's `private`, so maybe it's OK, but it means anyone calling `FindNodeByKey` needs to be very careful about `const`ness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have both overloads forward to an implementation template:

```
template<class T, class Compare = std::less<>, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>> 
class my_set {
public:
    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& value) {
        return insert_impl(value);
    }
    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&& value) {
        return insert_impl(std::move(value));
    }

private:
    template <typename V>
    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert_impl(V&& value)
    {
        // all the logic here, just eventually std::forward the value into the right
        // spot. We know at this point that V is either const value_type& or value_type
    }
};
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out why `insert_impl` is a template function. What is V type when `insert_impl` is called from the first `insert` overload?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky `const value_type&` (as noted in the comment). It needs to be a template simply because you need to either copy or move from the argument.

Comment: Then why `insert_impl(V&& value)` but not `insert_impl(V value)`? As far as I it also compiles. See live example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/X67iyOY5rW3CZeRQ

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Sure, but the goal isn't to simply compile, the goal is to be efficient. Don't want to just do extra moves.

Comment: Looks like I still do not quite understand how the universal references work, I need to think about this. But anyway what should I pass as the comparer argument?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You don't pass the comparison object around, it's a member of the set.

Comment: I mean what I pass to the comparer? const T & or T&&?

Comment: Theoretically I can pass `const std::remove_reference(V) &` or probably `const std::decay(V) &`. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You just pass `value`, the comparison object should take it by `const T&`.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't have a `Node * FindNodeByKey(Key&& key) const` overload. It doesn't make sense as you are not using the parameter `key` to make a copy of it. You are just using it to pass it (multiple times) to `m_comp` (which in turn doesn't make a copy of it).

You generally want `const T& x` and `T&& x` overloads when your function needs to make one and only one copy of `x`. Then you can optimize this in the case where the value passed is a temporary so instead of the copy you do a move.

As for your insert, yes here you can implement both overloads because `insert` fits perfectly into the above category. And both overloads should call `FindNodeByKey(const Key&)`

Comment: how to make the second `insert` overload call `FindNodeByKey(const Key&)`? Is it possible to convert  `Key &&` to `const Key &` ?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky you just call `FindNodeByKey(key)`. There is no need for any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate having to implement one of your overloads by simply calling the other overload from it:

```
std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type & value)
{
    return insert(value_type(value));
}
```

As long as your value_type has a copy constructor, this will create a temporary copy of value, and then call the overload of insert that takes an rvalue reference.

Comment: value_type and Key are not guaranteed to have copy constructors.

Comment: Then how do you propose to insert them by const reference? If you have a way of storing a copy of them, you have a way of copying them no?

Comment: In that case, I think you want `emplace` ala https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace. That can create a `Node`, in-place construct a value from `emplace`'s arguments, then use that copy that's in the `Node` to figure out where the `Node` goes in the data structure, then either insert it or destroy the `Node`.

Comment: Indeed. If the value_type truly isn't copy-able but can be constructed with arguments, than OP can implement emplace and call that instead. They could as well call insert on the temporary constructed this way. But if this is truly possible, then I don't see why value_type isn't copy-able in the first place.

Comment: This requires you to do an extra move.

Comment: The move will probably be elided by the compiler since its operating on a temporary (i.e. the temporary just becomes the argument in the function scope instead of moving into the argument)

Comment: It is not operating on a temporary.

Comment: This: return insert( value_type(value) ); 
_value_type(value)_ is an unnamed temporary. Upon calling insert, move is _usually_ ellided in modern compilers for c++11 and c++14. In c++17 in fact, the move is [guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to be ellided.

Comment: `value_type(value)` is a temporary. But that temporary is then bound to an rvalue reference, and it is that reference that is subsequently moved from. There is no move elision in this scenario.

Comment: Okay I see your point. Calling emplace with a value_type that has a working copy constructor would be the optimal solution then.